# Call a View from a class which extends Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've got a java class that extends Activity (not AppCompatActivity!).

Now it happens that I want to call a View which was defined in an .xml file.
How do I do that?
My app keeps crashing, but if I let the .java class extend AppCompatActivity, it doesn't.

Any ideas on how ti fix that?

Sadly it has to extend Activity.

**The .java class**

```
public class pop extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .4)); // Width * 0,8 == 80% der Fenstergröße

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Thats where it fails, because it couldnt get the parent-view.
                parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,0,0,0));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**pop.java**

```
public class pop extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Thats where it fails, because it couldnt get the parent-view.
                parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,0,0,0));
                finish();
            }
        });

        sure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I have already found teh solution, thank you all foor the help! I really appreciate that!

Comment: Please add your stack trace and your popup.xml

Comment: Edit your question to include the stack trace/log and also the layout in question. That will help people determine the cause and to then provide an answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`? I don't believe you can use anything from this due to it being an activity that you are using. i.e. seeing what is affected when you remove it may highlight the issue/cause.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference @MikeT, i tried it.

Comment: try replacing `parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,0,0,0));`  with `((RelativeLayout)view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,0,0,0));`

Comment: @MikeT it changes the Backgroundcolor of the pop.java class, not of the mainactivity... :D

Comment: Uhhm I suspect that will do exactly the same. I think what you are trying to do is set the background colour of the invoking activity, not the current activity's as you then `finish`. I'm not even sure you can alter another activities views but you could try passing the invoking activity's view's id via an intent. `findByView`, as I understand, will only find something in the current activity's context. Another alternative could be to to set a variable before calling the pop activity and then setting the background in the mainactivity.

Comment: @MikeT ah ok, then my question was just not good enough explained. Ima try it, ty for taking time!

Comment: Another option could be to start the activity for results [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and pass the colour back (I've never successfully used this as yet, but not really tried).

Comment: Ooops I didn't finish the comment before the last one, that is:-  .....and then setting the background in the mainactivity in the `onResume` method which will run when you return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way (as mentioned in the comments) utilising `onResume`, it's all handled in the invoking activity basically by setting a variable to indicate that the pop activity has been started (*note as you may be using a dialog that clicking out side the dialog would have the same effect*).

This is pretty limited.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean resumestate = false;
    LinearLayout ll; //The main layout

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_ll);

    }

    // Invoke the pop activity, setting resumestate to indicate this      
    public void doTestButton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"You Clicked the Test Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Pop.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        resumestate = true;
    }

    //Check if the activity was invoked and if so set background colour
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (resumestate) {
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,0,0,0));
            resumestate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another way, using `startActivityForresult` and thus returning the background colour via a returned Intent (more flexible) :-

**MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean resumestate = false;
    LinearLayout ll;
    int requestcode = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_ll);

    }

    public void doTestButton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"You Clicked the Test Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Pop.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode);
        resumestate = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int rqstcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
        if (rqstcode == requestcode) {
            if (resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int newcolour = data.getIntExtra("BGRNDCOLOUR",Color.argb(250,48,48,48));
                ll.setBackgroundColor(newcolour);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The button's `onClick` method in the **`pop` activity** :-

```
public void doTestButton(View v) {
    int newcolour = Color.argb(250,128,128,128);
    Intent ri = new Intent();
    ri.putExtra("BGRNDCOLOUR", newcolour);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,ri);
    finish();
}
```

---

A third way, which I think may be considered bad practice, would be to create a `public static` method to alter the background in conjunction with declaring the static variable for respective layout.

e.g. In the mainactivty replace `LinearLayout ll;` with `static LinearLayout ll;` and then add the appropriate method to main activity e.g.

```
    public static void alterBackGroundColour(int newcolour) {
        ll.setBackgroundColor(newcolour);
    }
```

then in the appropriate place in the `pop` activity use :-

```
    MainActivity.alterBackGroundColour(Color.argb(250,128,0,128));
```

Comment: @Sarius Great, I'd appreciate you marking it as answered and up-voting if you found the answer useful.

Comment: No problem budd